# JavaScript Converting System TimeZone + 15 minutes?

Tags: javascript, php, date, datetime, timezone-offset

My system time is UTC + 0 as I am in the UK.

**My Script:**

```
<script>
// Set the date we're counting down to
var countDownDate = new Date("<?php echo $date ?>").getTime();

// Update the count down every 1 second
var x = setInterval(function() {

    // Get todays date and time
    var now = new Date().getTime();

    // Find the distance between now an the count down date
    var distance = countDownDate - now;

    // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
    var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
    var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
    var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

    // Output the result in an element with id="demo"
    document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";

    // If the count down is over, write some text 
    if (distance < 0) {
        clearInterval(x);
        document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
        window.location.href = "/error";
    }
}, 1000);
</script>
```

My PHP will echo a date + 15 minutes gotten from the serverside, a users order will expire after 15 minutes you see.

So here is a date that the countdown timer would use (2017-11-23 22:50:18) this would be 15 minutes from now, but is UTC + 0 time.

If the users system time was in another country or behind then it would expire and go to the error page straight away.

How would I convert this time to the users timezone (And even if they refresh the page the timer would still be counting down)

The PHP var for $date is gotten from the database and is laid out like so: "2017-11-23 22:50:18"

How do I convert this to the system time of the user?

**I hope you understand me, thanks very much! :)**

Comment: A helpful rule of thumb is to store, transmit, and compute strictly in UTC, and only every convert to another timezone for user display.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, does anyone know how I would perform a conversion using the script?

Comment: @rakupu—No conversion required, Dates are UTC internally by default (they just present localised values for output). If you wan to see UTC values, use UTC methods (*getUTCHours*, *…Minutes*, etc.).